# Css positioning button at center of Overlay with image in background

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-position

```css
.msg-ex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.msg-ex .msg-ex-overlay {
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

.msg-ex .msg-ex-overlay .msg-ex-cta {
  position: absolute;
  color: red;
  background-color: #DCE0E3;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-weight: 700;
  border-radius: 18px;
  height: 38px;
  width: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-48%) translateY(-47%);
}

.msg-ex .msg-ex-overlay:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.msg-ex-box {
  position: relative;
  background-color: $voiceColor;
}

.msg-ex-box::after {
  content: '';
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background-image: url(../pics/data/img1.png);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}


}
.msg-ex-voice:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<div class="msg-ex msg-ex-box">
  <div class="msg-ex-overlay">
    <button class="msg-ex-cta">Show</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am positioning my "Show" button at the center using `transform: translateX(-48%) translateY(-47%);` but ideally it should be `transform: translateX(50%) translateY(50%);` which centers it - cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use following css for button which you want to make center

```
position:absolute;
top:50%;
left:50%;
transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
-ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
-moz-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
```

or

```
display:flex;
align-items:center;
justify-content:center;
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because the parent elements of `.msg-ex-cta` don't have a height. When you used `height: 100%;` for `.msg-ex-overlay` that percentage height needs a value to inherit from, no height is defined for it's parent so `100%` of `0` is `0`.

While adding `width: 100vw;` and `height: 100vh;` to `.msg-ex-overlay` likely gets you what you want, there's a chance that how the modal/overlay is being triggered might need to change. Though I'm not privy to your exact goals so I'll leave it as is until further notice.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.msg-ex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.msg-ex .msg-ex-overlay {
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

.msg-ex .msg-ex-overlay .msg-ex-cta {
  position: absolute;
  color: red;
  background-color: #DCE0E3;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-weight: 700;
  border-radius: 18px;
  height: 38px;
  width: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-48%) translateY(-47%);
}

.msg-ex .msg-ex-overlay:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.msg-ex-box {
  position: relative;
  background-color: $voiceColor;
}

.msg-ex-box::after {
  content: '';
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background-image: url(../pics/data/img1.png);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}


}
.msg-ex-voice:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<div class="msg-ex msg-ex-box">
  <div class="msg-ex-overlay">
    <button class="msg-ex-cta">Show</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to center anything, put this inside the parent:

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
```

And add this to the child you are trying to center:

```
align-self: center;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Have you actually tested this? How is this different that OP's solution? `align-items: center;` on the parent is the same difference as `align-self: center;` on the child in this situation. There's only one element `align-items: center;` can be applied to from the parent so you don't need to worry about some items centering that shouldn't.